# What happens behind the scene a method in abstract class create an instance of its derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Recently in an interview I was asked this question: I have an abstract class A and class B derives A. An abstract class has a method that creates an instance of the class B (derived). I know we can do this. And I think its a bad design. But I am not able to understand how does base class know about its derived class to create an instance of derived class.

Comment: you mean like A having a Method like `public static B CreateB(){ return new B();}` ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question *is* in this post.

Comment: Giving slightly misleading cues is a pretty standard interview technique.  It tests the ability of the candidate to work off an imperfect functional spec. You would probably have aced it by talking about the factory pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean something like:

```
abstract class A
{
    void Foo() { var b = new B(); /* now do something with b */ }
}
class B : A { }
```

Any code can reference any types that successfully resolve; if `A` can see `B`, then of course `A` can create a `B`, just like *any other code* can create a `B`.

What it *isn't* doing is saying "create an instance of my concrete type" - the `B` here is simply known statically. The "create an instance of my concrete type" would have to be done via reflection:

```
var a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(GetType());
```

(which would be brittle, as we don't know what the actual type will need to be meaningfully constructed)

Comment: Thanks Marc. That solves my confusion.